# RefernceError: Can't find variable: angular_formsWEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_

Tags: angular, mobile-safari

I have a website which works on desktop no problem but on iOS it throws error `RefernceError: Can't find variable: angular_formsWEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_` when I connect remotely to safari the error disappears and the site loads normally, anybody has a clue what could cause it? It uses `Angular 14.0.4` with not ejected webpack, i shuffled some parts around and now it says `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: _angular_material_form_field_WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_9` which makes me believe its not issue with my code per se, but rather webpack . To simplyfy my setup and in order to narow down the issue i removed all the modules and all directives & components are directly registered with AppModule, i was hoping that would help but no luck so far

UPDATE - narrowing it down little more it looks like importing NG_VALIDATORS breaks it

Answer (score 0):

updating from angular 14.0.4 to 15.2.9 fixed the issue

Comment: Still having this issue and I am on version 15.2.9

Comment: We came across this message in an Ionic/Angular/Capacitor app when running on older iOS versions (current is 16). Resolved by updating the .browerslistrc file according to a new Ionic project. https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#queries